# How to select time options?

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

in ruby, `my_form.html.erb` i have:

```
<%= f.input :doors, collection => :00, :15, :30, :45, prompt => "Select the time" %>
```

how do I go about allowing the user to select an hour and minutes in :15 minute intervals? I also am using simple_form.

Comment: refer to documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is minute_step:

```
<%= f.input :doors, {minute_step: 15}%>
<%= f.input :showtime, {minute_step: 15} %>
```